# How to configure Application Insights for different environments?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, system.diagnostics

I have a multi-tier web application that has been moved to Azure, however I would like to know how I can configure application insights for multiple environments as I have 3 separate resource groups for DEV, QA, and PROD. In each would like to have an instance of application insights to record diagnostic information for each environment but how would I configure this in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 parts to the answers for your question.

**Part 1**

As part of the configuring AI(Application Insights) in cloud, you just have to create a new instance in the respective resource groups and Azure will automatically configure it for you.

Now on the overview panel of the instance, get the `Application Insights Key` or the `Instrumentation key`. This key will act as an unique identifier to your instance to which you want to send telemetry to.

**Part 2**

Make use the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights package` in your project by installing it.

Have a look at the sample template code here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/console

Note: It is better to keep the `Intrumentation key` as part of the release variables of your CD pipeline, as it would be easy to manage all the 3 environments.

Comment: @Deepak_Ahire thank you for your answer, makes sense. I also found something related to this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/separate-resources